# Is there a way to add or remove an attribute as whole?

Tags: vue.js

With VueJS 1.x, I'm looking for a way to write this tag:

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

or this tag:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled">
```

decided by a value in the `$data`-model.

My problem is, everything I try to do like `v-bind:disabled` or else will at least write the word `disabled`, which is too much. Is there a way to write the full attribute as name-value-pair or to skip it as whole?

I am aware of `v-if` and components, but this seems overhead.
If somebody knows about this, thanks a lot for any hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look into the TodoMVC example of VueJS, the checkbox is done/checked using the data value.

To elaborate:

The HTML can be something like this :

```
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox" v-model="completed">
```

Where completed can be a true or false value in the $data.

JS:

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
completed: false
}
})
```

Now depending on the data value, the check box will be checked or unchecked.

If you want to have the disabled on the basis of the model, try doing something like this :

```
<input class="toggle" type="checkbox" v-model="completed" :disabled="someValue ? true : null">
```

Any falsy value removes the attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am aware that checkboxes' and radio boxes' checked state is bound to a model. My question is not about checking or unchecking, but about setting the `disabled` property bound to a value in the model.

Comment: @peter_the_oak : try my updated answer. Hopefully it should work.

Comment: I've created a fiddle to try your solution: [https://jsfiddle.net/h9sc7rmL/](https://jsfiddle.net/h9sc7rmL/) Thank you very much for the hint with the falsy return :-) This is valueable and elegant, didn't think of this. Though, I am not sure how much this is "abusing a side effect". But it works for now.

Answer (score 6):

While the given answer tells you how to set the disabled attribute, it doesn't answer the question how to add or remove attributes.

You can add and remove attributes with the v-bind attribute.

Component (saved as ExampleComponent.vue):

```html
<template>
    <any-tag v-bind="bindDisabled" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'ExampleComponent',
    props: {
        disabled: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    },
    data (){
        return {
            bindDisabled : this.disabled !== false ? { disabled: 'disabled' } : {}
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Use:

```html
<example-component :disabled="true" />
<example-component :disabled="false" />
```

DOM:

```html
<any-tag disabled="disabled"></any-tag>
<any-tag></any-tag>
```